# Sharepoint 2010 Advanced Search

Tags: 2010, jquery, advanced-search

This is the question related to the `Advanced Search`.

The second Test Box value "The Exact Phrase is getting cleared", once I search the required Word Documents (like Alerts, and Result Type = Word Documents) and search results are found. It is retaining the values when search results are not found.

[Source](http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/using-jquery-to-build-a-more-intuitive-advanced-search-experience-in-sharepoint-2010-part-2-advanced-aspx/#disqus_thread)